# Query a getElementInfo object in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, casperjs, cheerio

I am using casperjs and I got to a point where I have an object like so:

```
var domElem = this.getElementInfo(".foo");
```

And now I want to query domElem further on, like so:

```
var domElemChild = domElem.QUERYFUNCTIONHERE(".bar");
```

I can't do that because domElem is an object and not a DOM node, what can I do using (preferably) only casperjs?

Note: I tried using cheerio but it outputted the following error upon trying to require it:

> Error: Cannot find module 'util'
>   D:/dev/myproj/phantomjs:/bootstrap.js:289
>   D:/dev/myproj/phantomjs:/bootstrap.js:254 in require
>   D:/dev/myproj/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/Pars
>   er.js:120
>   D:/dev/myproj/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/Pars
>   er.js:351 Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   about:blank from frame with U RL file:///d:/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities depending on what you want to do with `domElem`.

The easiest might be to concatenate the CSS selectors:

```
var domElemChild = this.getElementInfo(".foo .bar");
```

Since the CSS path may return unexpected results depending on your document, the following XPath would work as intended:

```
var domElemChild = this.getElementInfo(x("(//*[contains(@class,'foo')])[1]//*[contains(@class,'bar')]"));
```

Everything else must be done in the page context. So you can do something like

```
var text = this.evaluate(function(){
  var domElem = document.querySelector(".foo");
  window._someDomElement = domElem; // save for later
  // DOM nodes cannot be passed out of the page context, so return the innerHTML
  return domElem.innerHTML;
});
// do something with `text`
var text = this.evaluate(function(){
  var domElemChild = window._someDomElement.querySelector(".bar");
  return domElemChild.innerHTML;
});
```

Something similar can be done using the [clientutils module](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html), but don't forget that this module can only be used inside of the page context.